# How to handle questions with inappropriate edits by other users?

Tags: discussion, edits

For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11660856/get-clicked-element-using-javascript) was edited to include the following (edit no longer visible unless you go into the edit history):

> Edit by Enes Unal : No need to downvote this question, think about it and you will find why He asks this..

To me, this edit seems inappropriate. It was edited by a user without editing privileges, and the OP accepted the edit.

However, since I also don't have editing privileges, my deletion of the edit would have to be peer-reviewed and would likely be denied by the OP. So how should I handle this?

Comment: That edit should've been a comment.

Comment: It was a funny race condition too (rejected and accepted at the same exact time: http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/329689)

Comment: It's lucky that the edit is on an active question - otherwise, it would have gone unnoticed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is indeed an inappropriate use of the edit feature. In fact, it's a textbook example of one of the reject reasons.

You should roll back the edit or, at least, remove it.

If the OP rejects your edit, flag it for a Moderator's attention. Use the "other" option and explain why it's flagged.

Comment: Thank you. I shall do this next time I see an inappropriate edit.